# Beginning CSS3 animation at different points

Tags: css, animation

I have some code for moving a div constantly across the screen using CSS3, and what I want to do is start an animation I have written in CSS at different points in the animation (i.e., 20%) during the first animation cycle, and from then on begin each cycle at 0%. Thank you for your help, JSFiddle below.

HTML:

```
<div class="x1">

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.x1 {
right: 30%;
top: 90px;
-webkit-animation: animato 15s linear infinite;
-moz-animation: animato 15s linear infinite;
-o-animation: animato 15s linear infinite;
animation: animato 15s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animato {
    0% { right: -25%; }
    20% { right: 0%; }
    40% { right: 25%; }
    60% { right: 50%; }
    80% { right: 75%; }
    100% { right: 100%; }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ER287/

How would I begin `animato` at the 20% mark, say?

Comment: Leave a comment at least if you're going to downvote my question. I don't understand what isn't valid about it.

Comment: Deliberately bypassing the jsFiddle only check is against the rules. [Read here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149890/prevent-posts-with-links-to-jsfiddle-and-no-code) to see the reason why there is such a check.

Comment: Comment: Use code blocks properly, please. It's not that much work to copy-paste into one. Also, if that particular fiddle is ever deleted, this question ceases to make any sense at all.

Comment: Alright, edited. Sorry about that

Comment: It's cool. At least we've gotten across the reason *why*, and you've understood that reason. One down, hundreds to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [negative `animation-delay`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/#animation-delay-property):

```
.x1 {
    right: 30%;
    top: 90px;
    -webkit-animation: animato 15s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: animato 15s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: animato 15s linear infinite;
    animation: animato 15s linear infinite;

    -webkit-animation-delay: -3s; /* offsets the animation starting point for 3/15 = 20% */
    -moz-animation-delay: -3s;
    -o-animation-delay: -3s;
    animation-delay: -3s;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ER287/2/)